# incomplete re.findall match

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to apply a regex to a string, but my match is incomplete.

```
import re

text = 'This car costs 15400 euros (15 400 €)'
regex = re.findall(r"\d+\s(euros?|€|tcc)?\s\(\d+\s?\d+\s?(euros?|€|tcc)\)", text)

print(regex)
```

output:

```
('euros', '€')
```

good output:

```
15400 euros (15 400 €)
```

Comment: Use non-capturing groups.

Comment: If you have euros and dollars you can do something like this : `\d+\s(euros|dollars)+\s\(\d+\s\d+\s(€|$)\)$` But if you have just euro : `\d+\s(euros)+\s\(\d+\s\d+\s€\)$` Good luck